# How to force UITableView custom cell to localise

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

My iOS app is in English, Arabic, and Russian, my app support iPhone and iPad, when change language to Arabic, it works so good on iPhone but on iPad it not work like images that attached down,how to force UITableView custom cell to localise?.

[Arabic iPhone version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMNAH.jpg)

[Arabic iPad version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36WqX.png)

Comment: I am not sure how are you coding, but using NSLocalizedString you should be able to localize your app, even using UITabaleView. I recommend you show how are you localizing, I will also put a very clear tutorial, I recommend a double check in every required step. http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your iPad cell layouts. I'm unaware of any iPad related issues like that, that may mean, given all tiny info you provide, that error is pretty simple. So I'd suggest to revise your iPad cell nibs/code (everything you have). If you don't find anything, than add details about your iPad cells, it's quite hard to tell, we can only guess.

Comment: @UlyssesR there's a lot more than just NSLocalizedString for the topic. Check the pictures, for arabic they must be mirrored.

Comment: @UlyssesR thanks for your fast replay I used this tutorial but my problem with icon please check the above images

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii I check everything, Its ok, what information that you need?

Comment: @Ahmed, Are you using "cell.imageView" from the default cell or you have an custom cell? are you using size class?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe how do you setup your constraints, do you use `trailing`, or `left` and stuff like that.

Comment: @UlyssesR, I don't use size classes, I used two storyboard one for iPhone and one for iPad, I used custom cell.

Comment: I agree with maniak, check the constraints, maybe something different are causing this behavior.

Comment: [link](http://workupload.com/file/VfBUZXHD)

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii, please check link.

Comment: @UlyssesR, please check link.

Comment: Watched the link, looks good, it is something else.

Comment: I have no way to test it, and I am not sure if will help, but, check this link the Flipping a Table View in a Mac App, it have a function that may also work in iOS, and may help you problem. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Comment: @UlyssesR, I try it but not work, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try everything finally I deleted tableview and set it again and set everything like normal its worked so good [Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JazvZ.png)